How to reformat strings, replacing first instance of character with set number of blanks
I require to reformat some strings, following a couple of rules:

Every dash after the first one should be removed (there should only ever be 2 dashes).

Text before first dash should be expanded to take up 6 characters adding spaces when necessary, and dash should be removed.


So for example, FE-95-0002 should end up looking like FE    950002. The second dash was removed, so 95 and 0002 combine, and because FE is only two characters, the first dash was replaced with 4 blank characters to bring the total to 6.
Some more examples below.
Current:
FE-95-0002
DEJIN-87-001
A-888-0111
ACT-78-0001

What I Want:
FE    950002
DEJIN 87001
A     8880111
ACT   780001


You can use str.replace with a custom function (capture everything before and after the first -, then pad the left part and remove the dashes from the right part):
df['out'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'([^-]+)-(.*)',
                                  lambda m: m.group(1).ljust(6)
                                           +m.group(2).replace('-', ''),
                                  regex=True)

Output:
            col            out
0    FE-95-0002   FE    950002
1  DEJIN-87-001    DEJIN 87001
2    A-888-0111  A     8880111
3   ACT-78-0001   ACT   780001

Output as list:
['FE    950002', 'DEJIN 87001', 'A     8880111', 'ACT   780001']

regex demo
([^-]+)  # match everything until the first dash and capture as group1
-        # match a dash
(.*)     # match the rest and capture as group2

And if you want to also align based on the maximum length as suggested by @e-motta, just further process with:
df['out'] = (df['col'].str.replace(r'([^-]+)-(.*)',
                                   lambda m: m.group(1).ljust(6)
                                            +m.group(2).replace('-', ''),
                                   regex=True)
             .pipe(lambda s: s.str.ljust(s.str.len().max()))
            )

Output:
            col            out
0    FE-95-0002  FE    950002 
1  DEJIN-87-001  DEJIN 87001  
2    A-888-0111  A     8880111
3   ACT-78-0001  ACT   780001 

Output as list:
['FE    950002 ', 'DEJIN 87001  ', 'A     8880111', 'ACT   780001 ']

The above will work with an arbitrary number of dashes, if you're sure you always have 2 you could also use:
df['out'] = (df['col'].str.replace(r'([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)',
                                   lambda m: m.group(1).ljust(6)
                                            +m.group(2)+m.group(3),
                                   regex=True)
             #.pipe(lambda s: s.str.ljust(s.str.len().max()))
            )


Thank you. I've tried this and it seems to work. Not overly familiar with Lambda or how the replace function is working by utilizing this, nor have I heard of the pipe method - but it is doing what I need it to do.

@TheDataPanda this is using a regular expression (I'll give more details in the answer). It's a very powerful tool, a bit tricky to learn but worth it.

Thank you. Your descriptions are very helpful.

split the column - with expand=True, then .str.pad the first part and concatenate the second and third:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"input": ["FE-95-0002", "DEJIN-87-001", "A-888-0111", "ACT-78-0001"]}
)

parts = df["input"].str.split("-", expand=True)

df["output"] = parts[0].str.pad(width=6, side="right") + parts[1] + parts[2]

print(df)

Output:
          input         output
0    FE-95-0002   FE    950002
1  DEJIN-87-001    DEJIN 87001
2    A-888-0111  A     8880111
3   ACT-78-0001   ACT   780001


Pandas shows the values right aligned by default (not sure how to change that), but you can verify they are correct:
print("\n".join(df["output"].tolist()))

Output:
FE    950002
DEJIN 87001
A     8880111
ACT   780001


You can use string method split and ljust to do the work as below
def modify_string(input_string):
    parts = input_string.split('-')
    first_part = parts[0].ljust(6)
    second_part = parts[1] + parts[2]

    # Return the modified string
    return first_part + second_part

More on ljust: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_ljust.asp

data = ["FE-95-0002", "DEJIN-87-001", "A-888-0111", "ACT-78-0001"]
s = pd.Series(data)

s = s.str.split("-", expand=True)
first = s[0]
first = first.str.pad(width=first.str.len().max() + 1, side="right")
second = s[1] + s[2]
second = second.str.pad(width=second.str.len().max(), side="right")
out = first + second

0    FE    950002 
1    DEJIN 87001  
2    A     8880111
3    ACT   780001 


Use Series.str.split with Series.str.ljust, numbers shift by maximal length by Series.str.len:
s = df['col'].str.split('-')
out = s.str[0].str.ljust(6) + s.str[1] + s.str[2]
df['new'] = out.str.ljust(out.str.len().max())
print (df)
            col            new
0    FE-95-0002  FE    950002 
1  DEJIN-87-001  DEJIN 87001  
2    A-888-0111  A     8880111
3   ACT-78-0001  ACT   780001 

